# How to show volume shadow copy service tab?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, windows-server-2008, services

There is a service called **volume shadow copy** that can help me to control my ***system restore*** points , this service can make me restore any thing ( e.g restore my files that I write at specific date ) , this service can make me control window c:\ operating system partition to make stable restore points that I can save and manipulate , **VSS** ( volume shadow copy service) can make me control the size of it at any partition (e.g 5 G ) , as we all know that VSS can help a lot beside backup , because it is so small and just save files indexes or nodes at any hard drive ( not the file it self )

my question is , when I started this service from computer right click

> manage > services and applications > services > volume shadow copy

, and I configured it as automatic start , after that I start

> storage >  Disk management > c:\ , and I made right click > properties

, after that I did not find the shadow copy tab ! , what shall I do to get this tab ?

for more information's look to this [three figures links](http://picsvv.blogspot.com/2015/01/blog-post_19.html)

## **Update**

1 - as [twisty](https://superuser.com/questions/866902/how-to-show-volume-shadow-copy-service-tab/866909#866909) answer I made an update to the figures , I found previous version but no configure shadow copy

2 - also I made stop to the volume shadow copy service , and I made restore point and backup and I found that it's still work ! ?

Answer (score 2):

The Shadow Copies tab had been renamed *Previous Versions* as shown in your 3rd screen shot. This is the case in at least Windows 7/Server 2008 and later (possibly even Vista and later).

Previous Versions/Shadow Copies are also configured differently in modern versions of Windows. A new command, **Configure Shadow Copies**, has been added to the context menu of a drive when accessed from My Computer.

Comment: I made an update to the figures , I found previous version but no configure shadow copy

Answer (score 0):

The command "Configure Shadow copies" within the context menu of the drive only exists on Windows Server OS.

As far as Windows client operating systems are concerned: You have to right-click "This PC" or "Computer" to open the System properties. Alternatively use the control panel on Windows 7 or the classic control panel (enter control in search box) on Windows 8 and Windows 10 to get to the system properties.

Then click System Protection, and there you have the detailed settings to configure shadow copy.
My recommendation is: Just activate it, the default settings are reasonable, and depending on the amount of file activity goes back about 31 days with two shadow copies each day.

For more details: See the configurable schedule on the shadow copies in windows task scheduler. For Server OS it is right within "configure shadow copies" where you have a nice GUI to set the schedule - sadly missing in the client OS.

For going back more days or versions that the default 64: https://www.google.com/search?q=MaxShadowCopies